# Name of JDBC Ressource Pool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I want to make connection in Java using a glassfish JDBC Pool.
But I don't know the name I should write in the ressource
like here : "jdbc/myDS"

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/myDS")
private DataSource ds;
```

I configured it in glassfish server. but i don't know how to get the full name?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use something like this

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/myDS")
private DataSource ds;
```

Comment: try to use mappedName instead of lookup then like @Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/myDS")

Comment: I have to add that I use it like this :
 @Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/myds")
  static DataSource ds;

and i use it in another method, but i gives me nullpointerexception. when i use it directly in the methode with lookup it works fine :
   javax.naming.Context ctx = new InitialContext();
   javax.sql.DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/myds");

Comment: why do you need to use "static". as far as I know you can't inject a static field?

Comment: I want to use the @ ressource annotation.

Comment: you shouldn't use static to use @Resource

Comment: how can i do Connection c = ds.getConnection(); then?

Comment: It doesn't have to be static to make such a call. Am I missing smth?

Comment: yes, if i make it non-static there's an error saying: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field.

Comment: Then you are making a call from a static method, right? If that is the case then there is no point of injection in a static context.

Comment: i made it no-static ad still the same problem.